# Relation between Pixel intensity values of Image and values returned by read_imagef in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

**The values returned by read_imagef in OpenCL are in the range 0 to 1 whereas the pixel intensity range is from 0 to 255...** i want to do further processing on the intensity values to do Image Segmentation which is based only on the intensity values (Operations carried out would be like finding difference between two intensity values, sorting, finding minimum, shuffling etc). How to get these values in the range 0 to 255 in an integer form(for convenience)...? **Can I just multiply every value with 255 or is there something else I need to do...?**

Answer (score 2):

**read_imagef** returns a **float4**, and can be used for images created with channel data types UNORM_INT8, UNORM_INT16, SNORM_INT8, SNORM_INT16, HALF_FLOAT, and FLOAT. The conversion rules are part of the [OpenCL specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf), and are given in section 8.3.1.

To answer your question, yes, if your image data type is UNORM_INT8, you can simply multiply by 255.

GPUs are generally faster with UNORM_INT8 than with UNSIGNED_INT8 images.

Comment: thanks for your answer Eric. i had specified the data type as CL_FLOAT to get the values in a non-normalized form, but the code gives a run time error saying "

Unhandled exception at 0x541e7802 in ImageFilter.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0x03e41000."

Why does such error occur...?